# jpg file content to var problems

Tags: javascript, php

I get jpg file content through `<?php $cont = file_get_contents("1.jpg") ?>` and then assign it to javascript var

```
var cont = '<?php echo $cont; ?>';
```

But it breaks me all structure of script. Example:

> http://in-social.name/erfer/ad/1.php

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Display the image?

Comment: If trying to display an image, your approach is incorrect. You could use Data URIs: http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/ Please tell us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json_encode` to convert a PHP value to a Javascript literal:

```
var cont = <?php echo json_encode($cont); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the raw jpg data will be unprintable characters like chr(0).

Try base64 encoding it using php:

```
var cont = '<?php echo base64_encode($cont); ?>';
```

You'll need to have it in that format to create an image data url anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?php 

$cont = file_get_contents("home.png"); // at place of home.png give your file.
//echo $cont;
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cont = '<?php echo base64_encode($cont); ?>';
    alert(cont);
});
</script>
```